# Programmatically changing Tor circuit

Tags: circuit

Is it possible to change Tor circuit using Javascript or configuring it to change Tor circuit in a certain interval?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969958/how-to-change-the-tor-exit-node-programmatically-to-get-a-new-ip

Answer (score 2):

It is called "NYM"-command.

> a certain interval?

1) Default interval is 10 minutes. You would change it in your torrc ( Configuration file ) read the f.. manual.

2) Also, you can always change circuit by telnet, You need to connect to Tor's control port, thereafter send there right command. Again, read the manual. You must login with you password.

3) In Unix-like systems, you would always change the circuit by one SIGNAL, often it is SIGHUP ( Number 1 ).

So,

```
kill -1 `pidof tor`
```

works for me.

Or,

```
kill -HUP `pidof tor`
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP

> Daemon programs sometimes use SIGHUP as a signal to restart themselves, the most common reason for this being to re-read a configuration file that has been changed.

Here, in Tor, "re-read a configuration file" - includes a building of new circuit for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should elaborate Tor Control protocol and for a quick note a `SIGNAL NEWNYM` command. Try to use Stem library and you can even custom-pick all the route.

Answer (score 0):

To automatically change the circuit on an interval, you can set `MaxCircuitDirtiness` in `torrc` (default 10 minutes). See full manual with `man tor`.